# How to pass runtime value as variables in sql query stored in properties file

Tags: java, mysql

I am involved in Framework Development for Database application where I store various sql queries in a properties file. Those queries are stored  stored in a in properties file with id value as variable i.e.

```
#query1 which finds deductible value
deductiblevalue=Select deductible from TableName Where planId='V_PLAN_ID';
```

where `V_PLAN_ID` is  a variable in the query.

`V_PLAN_ID` should be defined at run time, when I call `deductiblevalue` query from properties file, and run the query on a db.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `PreparedStatement`.

First, replace the variables with question marks, these are index based query variables:

```sql
deductiblevalue=SELECT `deductible` FROM `TableName` WHERE planId = ?;
```

Next, import the properties file and read the `String` into a `PreparedStatement`:

```
final Properties queries = //read somehow
try(final Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    final PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(queries.getProperty("deductiblevalue"))) {
}
```

Now, set the value for the variable - these are `1 - indexed` and typesafe:

```
statement.setInt(vPlanId);
```

And execute as normal

```
try(final ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
    //read results
}
```